# recommended practices to place allocation of arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, allocation

What are the recommendations or best practices regarding where should we allocate an array?

For instance, if I have a (simplified version of my) program as shown, I am allocating the output variable (the variable of interest) in the main program. This main program calls subroutine `foo`, which, in turn, calls subroutine `foo2`, who does the actual calculations.
My question is what is the best/recommended practice to where the allocation should be done.

- If `foo2` does the actual calculation, should it allocate the arrays?
- If `foo` calls `foo2`, should `foo` allocate the array and `foo2` do
  just the calculations?
- Should I write a new function/subroutine to just allocate the arrays?
- Or is it best to allocate on the main program and pass the arrays as
  assumed-shape?

If it is important, I have a module called global, that contains the derived types on main program, and the main parameters of the code, such as the size of each array (`Ni`, `Nj`, tolerances etc)

```
program main
    use global
    implicit none

    type(myVar_) :: ans

    Ni = 10
    Nj = 20

    if (allocated(ans%P)) deallocate(ans%P)
    allocate(ans%P(1:Ni, 1:Nj))

    call foo(ans)

    print *, P
end program main

module global
    integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)

    integer :: Ni, Nj

    type myVar_
        real(dp), allocatable :: P(:,:)
    end type myVar_

end module global

subroutine foo(myVar)
    use global
    implicit none

    type(myVar_) :: myVar

    call foo2(myVar%P)

end subroutine

subroutine foo2(P)
    use global
    implicit none

    real(dp), intent(inout) :: P(:,:)

    ! do calculations for P
end subroutine foo2
```

what is

Comment: I think"recommendations" and "best practices" are off topic in SO, it leads to many opinion based and non-falseable answers

Comment: **falsifiable .

Comment: this is a highly opinionated question. In my codes, allocations are performed right before they are used and deallocated immediately after use, otherwise where appropriate. However, one will have to keep in mind that allocations can be tremendously computationally expensive if they are done frequently, for example when they occur in a subroutine or function that is called many times. I have only seen giant old Fortran codes with lots of global variables, that allocate everything together in a specific subroutine. not sure if this is really a recommended practice, and I don't do it myself.

Comment: This is extremely opinion based. I have a 2-tier hirarchy: Allocate just before and deallocate just after use, but try to allocate outside of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed good practice to avoid allocation in low-level subroutines and function for performance reason. As you can see from [1], simple additions take about 1-3 CPU cycles, an allocation and deallocation pair (of a "small" array) can take between 200-500 CPU cycles.

I would suggest you to write a subroutine using a "work" variable as input and possibly operating in place (i.e. overriding the input with the result), e.g.

```
subroutine do_computation(input,output,work1,work2)
   work1 = ...
   work2 = ...
   output = ...
end subroutine
```

An you could make a wrapper function which makes the allocation for convenience:

```
subroutine convenient_subroutine(input,output)
   allocate(work1(...),work2(...)
   call do_computation(input,output,work1,work2)
   deallocate(work1,work2)
end subroutine
```

When performance is not critical, you can call the `convenient_subroutine`, but otherwise you call `do_computation` trying to share the work arrays between loop iteration and between different other subroutines.

[1] http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/